# i will visit him by early next week or i will visit him by earlier next week?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

Could anyone do the favor of sharing their thoughts on the following?

Which is correct? -

"I will visit him by earlier next week"

or

"I will visit him by early next week".

which is I need to visit him the beginning of next week, so can I use earlier next week/early next week to refer to 'the beginning of next week'? or are there other expressions?
I believe the context is self-explanatory ..it has no different meaning in the backdrop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is ungrammatical. An example using a comparative is

> I will visit him earlier than next week.

which means you will visit him this week.

---

The second sentence is grammatical

> I will visit him by early next week.

but it means you will visit him sometime between now and (say) Tuesday.

---

To say that you will visit him at the beginning of next week:

> I will visit him early next week.

Comment: "I will visit him earlier next week" is OK in the context of a weekly visit, say on Friday this week and before Friday next week. (But yes, *by* doesn't belong in that meaning either.)

Comment: Without context, 'earlier' needs a comparison, otherwise it reads like an advert: "our product is cheaper."

Comment: Appreciate your contribution.Thank you. Was very useful @WeatherVane

Comment: Thank you for your time. @AndrewLeach